# Start conversation with mutiple users in MS Lync

Tags: javascript, lync, lync-2013, ucwa

I want to start a conversation with multiple users . I am using below project
http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/04/ucwa-sample-project-online-chat-example/
I had assigned cpomma separated sips but it doesn't work. And it works properly for peer to peer.

```
destinationSIPAddress="user1@domain.com;user2@domain.com"

function StartNewConversation() {
        site.ucwa.Cache.read({
            id : "main"
        }).done(function (cacheData) {

            imData.sessionContext = site.ucwa.GeneralHelper.generateUUID();
            imData.operationId = site.ucwa.GeneralHelper.generateUUID();
            imData.to = destinationSIPAddress;
            site.ucwa.Transport.clientRequest({
                url : cacheData._embedded.communication._links.startMessaging.href,
                type : "post",
                data : imData,
                callback : function (data) {
                    if (data.status === 201) {
                        if (handlers.indexOf("conversation") === -1) {
                            handlers.push("conversation");
                            site.ucwa.Events.addEventHandlers({
                                rel : "conversation"
                            }, {
                                updated : handleConversation
                            });
                        }

                        if (handlers.indexOf("message") === -1) {
                            handlers.push("message");
                            site.ucwa.Events.addEventHandlers({
                                rel : 'message'
                            }, {
                                completed : handleMessage
                            });
                        }

                        if (handlers.indexOf("messaging") === -1) {
                            handlers.push("messaging");
                            site.ucwa.Events.addEventHandlers({
                                rel : "messaging"
                            }, {
                                updated : handleMessaging
                            });
                        }

                        site.ucwa.Events.startEvents();
                    } else {
                        cleanupMessaging();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [startOnlineMeeting](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-startOnlineMeeting) as that will allow multiparty communications from the start.  The calls for startOnlineMeeting and startMessaging are similar.  You should be able to pass an array as the as the **to** parameter containing the SIP addresses of the contacts.

If that does not work you could always stick with current code and call [addParticipant](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-addParticipant) providing the SIP addressed for the additional users.  You would gain access to this Href in the updatedConversation callback when the it becomes **Connected**.